# Wcf error with oledb database

Tags: c#, wcf, oledb

I was testing wcf service with oledb database. When I ran the project I encountered this error

```
The 'Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine
```

When I ran a winform project with oledb database it worked fine. 
So I have no idea what is the reason. Can wcf even work with oledb?

The method in wcf service which throw the exception

```
Public DataTable GetTopSixRecords()
{
playerDataTable.Rows.Clear();
command.CommandText="select top 6 * from Players order by score desc";
connection.Open();
adapter.Fill(playerDataTable);
connection.Close ();

return playerDataTable;
}
```

Comment: register oledb provider then.

Comment: How I register oledb provider? And if it worked with other projects, I'm assuming the provider is registered

Comment: Does your WCF project reference the same OleDB assembly as your Winform project?

Comment: I think so but I'm not sure, how can I check it?

Comment: Assuming you're using Visual Studio, in **Solution Explorer**, go to your WCF project and look under **References**.

Comment: FYI, in general people won't see your comments unless you prefix it with @someusername.

Comment: @jstreet yes I'm using visual studio. i didn't find in any of the projects reference to system.Data.oledb , Both though have reference to system.Data..

Comment: Have you seen [THIS](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/280/solved-the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine) ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to publish your wcf service application or library on 64-bit IIS.
To achieve this, go to Tools » Options » Projects And Solutions » Web Projects » General, select "use the 64-bit version of IIS express for websites and projects"
This worked for me, have a try.